# Handling of response in Background iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

In my app , I am triggering many GET/POST request and handling the response. But just after initiating the request if I lock the device then on resuming the app after some seconds the response doesn`t come.Is there any way to let the request active even in the background or on the device locked state till the response comes. I went through the Background Execution Docs in iOS but that seems to be used if want to download or do something in background.Not fulfilling my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Wen app is closed applicationDidEnterBackground was called so put this background task code. put timer or cal the function what ever u want.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
                   [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                   bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
             }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 
                                             0), 
                   ^{
                        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                    });

    ////  just u call the method want ever u want example

    [self notification];

    // (or) timer
   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(notification:)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:YES];
}
```

i think is help ful to u

Answer (score 0):

If you register a background task for each request, your app will keep running even when the device is locked, as long as a request is still active. The system only allows a maximum of 4 minutes though, so your requests mustn't take too long.

When you start a GET/POST request, do this:

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
}];
```

Then, store bgTask somewhere associated with your GET/POST request. Then when your request is complete, do this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
```